# how to install selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, spyder

I am using python 3.5.2, when am tryng to import the selenium it is throwing an error

> No module named selenium

below is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

Answer (score 1):

You should install the selenium package first.

```
pip install selenium
```

Answer (score 1):

I installed selenium through

```
pip install selenium
```

like yan said, but I still received the same error. The problem in my case was that selenium was installed on a different drive than my project was on (i.e. project was on D:, selenium was on C:). Moving both to the C: drive fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Install Python bindings for Selenium

```
pip install selenium
```

Step 2: Install the browser drivers

Selenium requires a driver to interface with the chosen browser.

Firefox, for example, requires [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases), which needs to be installed.

1. Get the executable from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) (just download one from the last release)
2. **Move the executable to your PATH**, e. g. ubuntu, place it in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`.

Note: Other supported browsers will have their own drivers available [more info here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#drivers)