# (Ubuntu) Python3 script runs fine but under Apache/wsgi it can't find selenium module

Tags: python, apache, selenium

Here are the results of when I install selenium:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-71:~$ pip3 install selenium
Collecting selenium
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/80/d6/4294f0b4bce4de0abf13e17190289f9d0613b0a44e5dd6a7f5ca98459853/selenium-3.141.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (904kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 911kB 1.6MB/s
Collecting urllib3 (from selenium)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e8/74/6e4f91745020f967d09332bb2b8b9b10090957334692eb88ea4afe91b77f/urllib3-1.25.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 9.2MB/s
Installing collected packages: urllib3, selenium
Successfully installed selenium-3.141.0 urllib3-1.13.1    // so the installation worked.
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Here is my python script (helloworld.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from selenium import webdriver

def testPrint():
    return "Test print"

def application(environ,start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    html = '<html>\n' \
           '<body>\n' \
           '<div style="width: 100%; font-size: 40px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">\n' \
           'Hello world! \n' + testPrint() + \
           '</div>\n' \
           '</body>\n' \
           '</html>\n'
    response_header = [('Content-type','text/html')]
    start_response(status,response_header)
    return [html]
```

It compiles under normal circumstances:

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx:/var/www/html/pythonscrape$ python3 helloworld.py
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx:/var/www/html/pythonscrape$
```

As you can see it has no problem compiling the line "from selenium import webdriver"

```
ubuntu@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx:/var/www/html/pythonscrape$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Oct  8 2019, 13:06:37)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>>
```

So as you can see no errors.

However when I run it via my browser/Apache/wsgi it can't find my selenium module.  Here is the log output:

```
[Fri Feb 21 14:43:34.952035 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15279] [client 108.210.66.3:64700] mod_wsgi (pid=15279): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/pythonscrape/helloworld.py'.
[Fri Feb 21 14:43:34.952130 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15279] [client 108.210.66.3:64700] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Feb 21 14:43:34.952207 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15279] [client 108.210.66.3:64700]   File "/var/www/html/pythonscrape/helloworld.py", line 3, in <module>
[Fri Feb 21 14:43:34.952318 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15279] [client 108.210.66.3:64700]     from selenium import webdriver
[Fri Feb 21 14:43:34.952396 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15279] [client 108.210.66.3:64700] ImportError: No module named selenium
```

Here is my helloworld.conf file:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /helloworld /var/www/html/pythonscrape/helloworld.py

ErrorLog /var/www/html/pythonscrape/error_log.txt

<Directory /var/www/html/pythonscrape/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

What can I do to get the selenium module to be recognized by Apache/wsgi?

Comment: Is the selenium installation on the same drive that your project is on? I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999613/how-to-install-selenium/51108993#51108993)

Comment: Hi Kosaro, how do I find out where selenium is installed?  When I type "which selenium" it returns blank.

Comment: in the python terminal `import selenium` `selenium.__file__` should give you the filepath of the module

Comment: Hi Kosaro, it shows -  /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/__init__.py    do I need to include that in my configuration somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are installing the module as the "ubuntu" user, but Apache runs under a different secure user account.   Your Apache server won't have any knowledge of the user install of the selenium module, and will not see the selenium module.

A quick fix is to install the module globally, for all users.  A more sophisticated solution is to create a virtual environment used by the Apache server.

For the quick fix (global install):

`sudo pip3 install selenium`

```
Collecting selenium
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/80/d6/4294f0b4bce4de0abf13e17190289f9d0613b0a44e5dd6a7f5ca98459853/selenium-3.141.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (904kB)
    100% |################################| 911kB 1.8MB/s 
Collecting urllib3 (from selenium)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e8/74/6e4f91745020f967d09332bb2b8b9b10090957334692eb88ea4afe91b77f/urllib3-1.25.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125kB)
    100% |################################| 133kB 7.1MB/s 
Installing collected packages: urllib3, selenium
Successfully installed selenium-3.141.0 urllib3-1.25.8
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

The module is now installed in a global location (/usr/local) and available to Apache:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Oct  8 2019, 13:06:37) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import selenium
>>> selenium.__file__
'/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/__init__.py'
>>>
```

Comment: Hi Chuck, the quick fix "sudo pip3 install selenium" didn't work.   Can I pass a system environment in apache instead of creating a virtual environment?

Comment: @BrentHeigold - If you are running ubuntu xenial, your Apache server may be using python 2 instead of python 3.  The "#!/usr/bin/python3" at the top of your script only works from bash, not from mod_wsgi. Please add the following to your test:   import sys    Then also include ','.join(sys.path()) on your debugging print output.   On my computer, Apache was using python2, and a global python2 install of selenium via `sudo pip install selenium` worked fine.

Comment: To upgrade your Apache mod_wsgi to use python3, and the global packages from python3, use:  `apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3`
Please note your script won't run under wsgi py3, which needs byte output.  You need to change OLD `return [html]` to NEW `return [html.encode()]`

Comment: Please be sure to restart Apache after upgrading to the py3 module.  To confirm the exact Python Runtime being used by mod_wsgi, look at:  `/var/local/apache2/error.log`    In my case, I previously saw `mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.12.` then after upgrading to libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 and restarting, it was `mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.5.2.`

Comment: THANK YOU, It was installing the libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 that did it.  I really appreciate this Chuck.